# add Async methods to class in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

How can I improve my class with Async methods?

Example, the WCF Service support adding Async methods to the class they generate and in the UI I just have to call to a complete event.

I try to search on details but I cannot find any information about this.

Could any one provide a little sample code?

Thank you very much

Comment: this is quite an open-ended question.  You probably should be more specific.  SO is really not here to save you from reading the docs.  Anyhow, in general, WPF and WinForm programs benefit greatly from the async/await keywords because these programs usually need to do things on the main UI thread -- async/await simplifies the task greatly for you because they default to execute continuations on the UI thread, saving you from having to wrap your continuation code in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke all the time.  I am not sure if WCF benefits as much though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Asynchronous Programming Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx)

[Asynchronous Programming Design Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969.aspx)

> An asynchronous operation that uses the IAsyncResult design pattern is
>   implemented as two methods named BeginOperationName and
>   EndOperationName that begin and end the asynchronous operation
>   OperationName respectively. For example, the FileStream class provides
>   the BeginRead and EndRead methods to asynchronously read bytes from a
>   file. These methods implement the asynchronous version of the Read
>   method.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super-quick not-very-robust example I threw together that is a template for what I've used before:

```
public interface IResponse
{
    string ResponseCode { get; }
}

public sealed class Response : IResponse
{
    private readonly string responseCode;

    private Response(string responseCode)
    {
        this.responseCode = responseCode;
    }

    public string ResponseCode { get { return this.responseCode; } }

    public static IResponse Create(string responseCode)
    {
        return new Response(responseCode);
    }
}

public sealed class DoItCompletedEventArgs : AsyncCompletedEventArgs
{
    private readonly IResponse response;

    public DoItCompletedEventArgs(
        Exception error,
        bool canceled,
        object userState,
        IResponse response) : base(error, canceled, userState)
    {
        this.response = response;
    }

    public IResponse Response { get { return this.response; } }
}

public interface IDoStuff
{
    event EventHandler<DoItCompletedEventArgs> DoItCompleted;

    bool CanProcessAsynchronously { get; }

    IResponse DoIt(string[] args);

    void DoItAsync(string[] args);
}

public sealed class DoStuff : IDoStuff
{
    private delegate IResponse DoItDelegate(string[] args);

    public event EventHandler<DoItCompletedEventArgs> DoItCompleted;

    public bool CanProcessAsynchronously { get { return true; } }

    private DoStuff()
    {
    }

    public static IDoStuff Create()
    {
        return new DoStuff();
    }

    public IResponse DoIt(string[] args)
    {
        return Response.Create(args.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, arg) => current + arg));
    }

    public void DoItAsync(string[] args)
    {
        DoItDelegate doIt = this.DoIt;

        doIt.BeginInvoke(args, this.DoDoItCompleted, doIt);
    }

    private void DoDoItCompleted(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var doIt = result.AsyncState as DoItDelegate;

        if (doIt == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var response = doIt.EndInvoke(result);
        var doItCompleted = this.DoItCompleted;

        if (doItCompleted != null)
        {
            doItCompleted(this, new DoItCompletedEventArgs(null, false, null, response));
        }
    }
}

internal static class Program
{
    private static void Main()
    {
        var doStuff = DoStuff.Create();

        if (doStuff.CanProcessAsynchronously)
        {
            var response = doStuff.DoIt(new[] { "stuff 1 ", "more stuff 1" });

            Console.WriteLine(response.ResponseCode);
        }
        else
        {
            doStuff.DoItCompleted += DoItCompleted;
            doStuff.DoItAsync(new[] { "stuff 2 ", "more stuff 2" });
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void DoItCompleted(object sender, DoItCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Response.ResponseCode);
    }
}
```